# md5 password query check through c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

**Database query in SQL Server side.**

```
declare @password varchar(100) = '12345aA!'

select user_id, username from tblusers 
where password=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', @password), 2);
```

This query works fine and below is the output. It gives one record, ok?

[image]

**Below is C# code to validate password**

```
var query = "select user_id from tblusers";
query += " where password=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', @password), 2);";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("backend");
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", form.password);
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                //not entering in this scope
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Due to some reasons c# code is unable to validate password through sql query. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Side note, you may want to do the hashing on the server side rather than passing the plain text password to the database. In addition, MD5 is rather weak (ok, yes, you can Google search basically any hash and trivially find the input. The rainbow tables are out there, plus collisions, plus it's been found to be insecure, etc. Don't use it), especially when you don't have a salt.

Comment: @gunr2171 "rather weak" should be "woefully insecure"

Comment: Disregarding any potential security issues already pointed out, I think your problem is that your script uses `varchar` for the password, but C# will default to `nvarchar`.  Since hashing is about bytes, you're hashing twice as many bytes.  This is why every database field in your database should be `nvarchar`.  You also get performance issues with `varchar`.

Comment: @JoséRamírez `varchar` still has uses (e.g. for storing non-human-readable always-ASCII text) as well as for UTF-8 storage in SQL Server 2019+. Also, what "performance issues" with `varchar` are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: @Dai problems with performance come when you don't account for `varchar` and just send strings in C# through params.  SQL Server then starts conversion of the table values to `nvarchar` seriously hitting the query performance.  So one has to either be very careful when querying everywhere or just move to `nvarchar` and forget `varchar` whenever possible.

Comment: @JoséRamírez What do you mean by "send strings in C# through params"? Whenever you use `SqlParameter` you need to specify the `SqlDbType` so that isn't an issue (assuming people aren't using [the broken `AddWithValue` method](https://www.dbdelta.com/2018/02/03/addwithvalue-is-evil/)).

Comment: @Dai you mean like the code from the OP that only passes the password and doesn't specify a data type?  You tell me.

Comment: @JoséRamírez Yes, right - but `AddWithValue` has issues with more types than just `varchar`.